# Implement ILockBytes in C# (for I_IrmProtector)

Tags: c#, com

I need to invoke functions of the Microsoft Office Protector (OpcIrmProtector) from C#. This protector implements the `I_IrmProtector` interface (details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475158%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Calling `HrInit()` is no problem.

But for e.g. `HrIsProtected()` I need to provide an implementation of `ILockBytes`. Has anybody experience how to correctly implement `ILockBytes` in managed code? I am a bit at a loss as to what is expected here.

For unmanaged code I found a sample that uses `CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal()`. This returns an unmanaged instance of `ILockBytes`. Is there any chance of using this unmanaged instance from managed code (probably not...) or marshalling it into a managed structure? Or is there a similar method for C#? In that case I wouldn't have to implement `ILockBytes`, which would save me a lot of time.

Of course, I could implement this part in unmanaged code, but I'd prefer a solution in managed code, if possible...

Thank you!

Comment: You have an example if ILockBytes and CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal here: http://xlsgen.arstdesign.com/core/inmemory.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it. I googled a lot, but this is the first useful link!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Download [AD RMS Bulk Protection tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11122) from Microsoft and then decompile it using something like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).  This uses the IrmProtectorWrapper, MsoIrmProtector and OpcIrmWrapper DLLs.